# Blazor Howto - looking for winform MessageBox() alike function

Tags: asynchronous, events, async-await, blazor

I m using VS 2019 and Blazor Server Net5. The included bootstrap 4 environment offers modal dialogs and I would like to replicate something like the MessageBox() from good old Windows Forms. This means you execute (withhin a button click event) something like

DialogResult x = [await] MessageBox[Async]("SomeMsg", SomeButtons+SomeIcon);

And in x you would find what option the user did click (DialogResult.OK, Cancel, ...).

So I found several samples how to show the model dialog itself, and write it even as a component.

I have a simple component MessageBox.razor

```cs
    public enum ModalResultType { Closed = 0, OK = 1, Cancel = 2, }
    
    @if (ShowMessageBox == true)
    {
       <div class="modal fade show d-block" id="MessageBox" tabindex="-1"
          role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
       .... and so forth ....
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
          @onclick="() => OnButtonClick(ModalResultType.Closed)">X</button>
       ... and so forth ...
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"
          @onclick="() => OnButtonClick(ModalResultType.OK)">OK</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
          @onclick="() => OnButtonClick(ModalResultType.Cancel)">Cancel</button>
       .. and so forth ...
       </div>
    }
```

and in the cs behind file I can turn on the component show flag and display the component.

```cs
    public async Task<ModalResultType> ShowAsync(string title, string messagetext)
    {
       Title = title;
       Message = messagetext;
       ShowMessageBox = true;
       StateHasChanged();
       //
       // Now I m at a loss... how to await here what the User did click???
       //
       return whatTheUserDidClick;
    }

    // Click event from button, called with the appropiate ModalResultType
    //
    public async Task OnButtonClicked(ModalResultType value)
    {
       ShowMessageBox = false;
       //
       // Now I am at a  loss - how to pass the clicked value into the waiting context
       // of the UI above from and "complete" the awaiting ShowAsync();
       //
    }
```

The overall idea is to put into the framing App.Razor-Component this MessageBox component and so every "page" or other component has (via cascading parameter) access to the message box. And if it would need to create a modal MessageBox dialog, for example from some button click event, it could simply do so by calling

```cs
    [CascadingParameter] public MessageBoxComponent AppRazorMessageComonent {get;set;}
    
    public async Task SomeClickEvent()
    {
       // get some form data
       // process them
       // question arises ask user if to proceed or defer
       if (await AppRazorMessageComponent.ShowAsync("Attention", "Shall we proceed?") == ModalResultType.OK)
       {
          // do stuff
       }
       else
       {
          // do other stuff
       }
    }
```

I found sample of modal dialogs where the event handler then is bound right to action to be carried out - like deleting a record. But this is not what I want - I would need to specifically bind the html always to the specifics of the page or component I m in at the time. Or I would need to supply a callback function, which would break my current track; like to set the ShowMessageBox flag, return from the click event, and then proceed along with the logic in another method.

So the question is: how can I await for an event withhin an event handler, which is triggered by an other UI event?

Do I need threads for this - I dont think so. It should be possible by Task, async and await only. But how to create an awaitable object, "signal" the completion, or cancellation, of such a Task? And in a way that it works withhin the Blazor UI component environment.

Comment: That is a feature for every Blazor component framework. [Here](https://gist.github.com/conficient/ba98d1662c659e170ec16650acea05c8) is a simple DIY one.

Answer (score 2):

I made use of the `System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim` class to acheive the awaitable result in `ValueTask<ModalResult<T>> OpenModal()` in `Modal.cs`

[BlazorRepl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/wbkfwIYf37sCrDts17)

`ModalLauncher.razor`

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @if (ModalContent is not null)
    {
        @ModalContent
    }
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>
```

`ModalLauncher.razor.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

public partial class ModalLauncher : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    public RenderFragment ModalContent { get; set; }

    public void ShowModal(RenderFragment renderFragment)
    {
        ModalContent = renderFragment;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void CloseModal()
    {
        ModalContent = null;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Wrap this around your Layout.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<ModalLauncher>
    <div class="page">
        ...
    </div>
</ModalLauncher>
```

`Modal.cs`

```
public class Modal<T> : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<ModalContext<T>> ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public ModalLauncher Launcher { get; set; }

    public async ValueTask<ModalResult<T>> OpenModal(T value)
    {
        var modalContext = new ModalContext<T> { Modal = this, Value = value };
        RenderFragment renderFragment = ChildContent.Invoke(modalContext);
        Launcher.ShowModal(renderFragment);
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        return new ModalResult<T> { ModalAction = modalAction, Value = value };
    }

    public void CancelModal() => CloseModal(ModalAction.Cancel);
    public void CloseModal() => CloseModal(ModalAction.Close);
    public void OkModal() => CloseModal(ModalAction.Ok);

    private void CloseModal(ModalAction action)
    {
        modalAction = action;
        Launcher.CloseModal();
        semaphore.Release();
    }

    private ModalAction modalAction;
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
}
```

```
public enum ModalAction
{
    Cancel,
    Close,
    Ok,
}

public class ModalContext<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public Modal<T> Modal { get; set; }
}
public class ModalResult<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public ModalAction ModalAction { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

***Usage***
Note: When I define the modals I only use a type, They are not bound to an instance. When you call `OpenModal(...)` you can pass an instance then.

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="@OpenSomeClassModal">Run Demo</button>

<Modal @ref="someClassModal" T="SomeClass">
    ...   
    <input type="number" @bind-value="@context.Value.SomeValue" />
    ...
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="@context.Modal.CancelModal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@context.Modal.OkModal">Save changes</button>
    ...             
</Modal>

<Modal @ref="someStringModal" T="string">
    ...
    <p> @context.Value</p>
    ...
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="@context.Modal.OkModal">Close</button>
    ...
</Modal>


@code {
    Modal<SomeClass> someClassModal;
    Modal<string> someStringModal;

    async Task OpenSomeClassModal()
    {
        var someClass = new SomeClass { SomeValue = 9 };
        var result1 = await someClassModal.OpenModal(someClass);
        var result2 = await someStringModal.OpenModal($"The value was set to {result1.Value.SomeValue}, you pressed {result1.ModalAction}");
    }
}
```

You also need to override part of the bootstrap `.modal` class. Put this in `wwwroot\css\app.css`:

```
.modal {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that led to some insights.

Comment: @PhilippOtt You may want to look at this ive been tinkering with: https://github.com/BrianLParker/HowToModal